# Trying to add a user inputted number of players to a consol based roulette game

Tags: java, object, input, roulette-wheel-selection

So what I have here is a fully functioning roulette game in java, running on eclipse. I want to improve it beyond What it was supposed to be by allowing the user to specify how many players they want to be in the same game, as opposed to the two hardcoded players. currently I put a way to set individual names for player 1 and 2 so me and a friend could play but I feel this would make it more universal. The goal is to take the code I have now and learn how to take a specified number, throw it into a loop to generate player objects (each with their own name) and have the program still function.

I have three classes, the Player class witch holds my constructors and payment methods, and getName() getMoney() methods as well. the Roulette class witch is the main method for the program where this loop to add player objects should be added. and the Wheel class where the randomly generated ball position is held and so forth.

here is the first class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//************************************************************************
//   Class Player represents one roulette player.
//************************************************************************
public class Player
{
    private int bet, money, betType, number, betNet;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static int houseWins;
    private String name;
    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //=====================================================================
    //  The Player constructor sets up  name and initial available money.
    //=====================================================================
    public Player (String playerName, int initialMoney)
    {
        name = playerName;
        money = initialMoney;
    } // constructor Player

    //=====================================================================
    //  Returns this player's name.
    //=====================================================================
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }  // method getName


    //=====================================================================
    //  Returns this player's current available money.
    //=====================================================================
    public int getMoney()
    {
        return money;
    }  // method getMoney

    //=====================================================================
    //  returns the net bets for that player
    //=====================================================================
    public int getNet()
    {
        return betNet;
    }

    //=====================================================================
    //  Prompts the user and reads betting information.
    //=====================================================================
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void makeBet(Wheel Wheel)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How much do you want to bet " + name + "? : ");
        bet = scan.nextInt();

        if(bet>=money)
        {
            System.out.println("im going all in!");
            bet= money;
            money = money-bet;
        } 
        else 
        {
            money = money-bet;
        }
        Wheel.betOptions();

        System.out.println("Choose your bet type: ");
        betType = scan.nextInt();

        if(betType == 3){
         System.out.println("your'e betting on: a number");
             while(true){

               System.out.println("Please enter the number you "
                    + "wish to bet on from 1 to 36: ");
               number = scan.nextInt();
               if(number <1 || number > 36)
               {
                 System.out.println("This Number is not in "
                        + "the desired range.");
                 }
               else
               {
                 break; 
               }
     }
    }
  }
    // method makeBet


    //=====================================================================
    //  Determines if the player wants to play again.
    //=====================================================================
    public boolean playAgain(Scanner scan)

    {

          String answer;

          System.out.println (name + " Play again [Y/N]? ");
          answer = scan.nextLine();


          return (answer.equals("y") || answer.equals("Y"));

    }

    // method playAgain

    public void payment(Wheel Wheel2)
    {
        int winnings = Wheel2.payoff(bet, betType, number);
        money += winnings;
        if(winnings > 0)
        {
            betNet += (winnings-bet);
            Roulette.setHouseWins(-(winnings-bet));
        }
        else
        {
            betNet -= bet;
            Roulette.setHouseWins((bet));
        }

        // =========================================================
        // if player runs out of money.
        // =========================================================
          if(money < 1)
          {

          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println(name + ", you're out of money. "
                + "Do you want to bet more? [Y/N] ");
          String answer= scan.nextLine();
          if(answer.equals("y") || answer.equals("Y"))
          {
              if (betNet>-200)
              {
                System.out.println("You bought back in for 100");
                money +=100;
              }
              else {
                  System.out.println("Sorry buddy, your cutt off from the credit line.");
                  money = 0;
              }
     }
    }
          //setHouseWins(betNet);
          System.out.println(" Testing to see how much is "
                + "betNet keeping track of: " + betNet);

   }

}
```

Then here is the Wheel class:

```
//************************************************************************
//   Class Wheel represents a roulette wheel and its operations.  Its
//   data and methods are static because there is only one wheel.
//************************************************************************
public class Wheel
{
    // public name constants -- accessible to others
    public final static int BLACK     =  0;         // even numbers
    public final static int RED       =  1;         // odd numbers
    public final static int GREEN     =  2;         // 00 OR 0
    public final static int NUMBER    =  3;         // number bet
    public final static int MIN_NUM   =  1;         // smallest number to bet
    public final static int MAX_NUM   = 36;         // largest number to bet

    // private name constants -- internal use only
    private final static int MAX_POSITIONS = 38;    // number of positions on wheel
    private final static int NUMBER_PAYOFF = 35;    // payoff for number bet
    private final static int COLOR_PAYOFF  = 2;     // payoff for color bet

    // private variables -- internal use only
    private static int ballPosition;                // 00, 0, 1 .. 36
    private static int color;                       // GREEN, RED, OR BLACK

    //=====================================================================
    //  Presents welcome message
    //=====================================================================
    public static void welcomeMessage()
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to a simple version of roulette game.");
        System.out.println("You can place a bet on black, red, or a number.");
        System.out.println("A color bet is paid " + COLOR_PAYOFF + " the bet amount.");
        System.out.println("A number bet is paid " + NUMBER_PAYOFF + " the bet amount.");
        System.out.println("Have fun and good luck!\n");
    }


    //=====================================================================
    //  Presents betting options
    //=====================================================================
    public static void betOptions()
    {
        System.out.println("Betting Options:");
        System.out.println("    1. Bet on black");
        System.out.println("    2. Bet on red");
        System.out.println("    3. Bet on a number between " + MIN_NUM +
                " and " + MAX_NUM);
        System.out.println();
    }
    //=====================================================================
    //  method spins the wheel
    //=====================================================================
    public int spin()
    {
        ballPosition= (int)(Math.random() * MAX_POSITIONS + 1);;
        if(ballPosition < 37)
        {
         if(ballPosition % 2 == 0)
         {
             color = BLACK;
         }
         else
         {
             color = RED;
         }   
               }
                else
               {
                color = GREEN;
               }
        System.out.print("the Result is: "+ ballPosition
                + " and color is: ");
        if (color == BLACK)
        {
            System.out.println("BLACK.");
        } 
        else if (color == RED)
        {
            System.out.println("RED.");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("GREEN.");
        }
        return ballPosition;
    }
    //=====================================================================
    //  calculates the payoff
    //=====================================================================
    public int payoff( int bet, int betType, int number)
    {
        if (color == GREEN)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (betType == 1 && color == BLACK)
        {
            return bet * COLOR_PAYOFF;
        }
        else if (betType == 2 && color == RED)
        {
            return bet * COLOR_PAYOFF;
        }
        else if (betType == 3 && number == ballPosition)
        {
            return bet * NUMBER_PAYOFF;
        } else return 0;

    }
}
```

and Finally the main method roulette class:

```
import java.util.*;

//************************************************************************
//   Class Roulette contains the main driver for a roulette betting game.
//************************************************************************
public class Roulette
{
     private static int houseMoney=0;
    //=====================================================================
    //  Contains the main processing loop for the roulette game.
    //=====================================================================
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name1 = "jane"; String name2 = "don";
        Wheel wl1 = new Wheel();
        System.out.println("please enter a name for player 1: ");
        name1 = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("please enter a name for player 2: ");
        name2 = scan.nextLine();
        Player player1 = new Player (name1, 100);   // $100 to start for Jane
        Player player2 = new Player (name2, 100);   // $100 to start for Dave
        boolean bl1 = true;
        boolean bl2 = true;

        Wheel.welcomeMessage();

        while (bl1 || bl2)
        {
            System.out.println ("Money available for " + player1.getName()
                    + ": " + player1.getMoney());
            if(bl1)player1.makeBet(wl1);

            System.out.println ("Money available for " + player2.getName()
            + ": " + player2.getMoney());
            if(bl2)player2.makeBet(wl1);

            wl1.spin();

             if(bl1 == true)
             {
                    //initiate the payment
             player1.payment(wl1);

             System.out.println ("Money available for " + player1.getName() + ": "
                     + player1.getMoney());

                    // check weather play the game again

                 if(!player1.playAgain(scan))

                 {

                    bl1 = false;

                     System.out.println(player1.getName()+" total wins/losses: " 
                     + player1.getNet());

                 }

             }

               // check the boolean value

               if(bl2 == true)

               {

                    //initiate the payment

                    player2.payment(wl1);

                    System.out.println ("Money available for " +
                            player2.getName() + ": " + player2.getMoney());

                    // check weather play the game again

                   if(!player2.playAgain(scan))

                    {

                         bl2 = false;

                         System.out.println(player2.getName()+ " total wins/losses: "
                                 + player2.getNet());

                    }
               }    
            } 
                System.out.println();

                 System.out.printf("House %s: $%d", houseMoney > 0 ? "Wins" : "Losses", houseMoney);

                 System.out.println();

                 System.out.println ("Game over! Thanks for playing.");

           }
    public static void setHouseWins(int Winnings)

    {

        houseMoney += Winnings;

   }

}
```

ive tried a few different ways to generate the player objects but I think the real issue is coming up with a boolean object for each respective player that wants to quit to be able to stop playing. please help a guy out! (Ps: feel free to use this program as a basis for your own roulette games as it does function quite well as is.)

Comment: The Player class should be a Java object that contains all of the information about a player, and **no** inputs or outputs.  You need to create a game model Java class that contains all of the game information, including a List of Player instances.  The Roulette class should be the class that contains **all** of the inputs and outputs.